# How to check multible boolean values true or false in java>

Tags: java

I have 8 boolean values. I want to rollback when one or more of 8 booleans have false.

```
boolean flag = false;
        boolean flag1 = false;
        boolean flag2 = false;
        boolean flag3 = false;
        etc,,.

flag = dbCall...
```

here the flag value changes.

Here I have to check manually like

```
    if(flag == false && flag1 == false && ....){
      userTransaction = rollback;
    }else{
     userTransaction = commit;
    }
```

is there any simple way to check multple boolean values in java.

Comment: You're not checking, but assigning in your second example.

Comment: negation of simple and between all of them

Comment: @alex modified my code.

Comment: As another way of thinking about this, why do you have 8 booleans? Do you ever need them individually?

Comment: Not required, but I have 8 db calls. If I get any error I want to rollback my code.

Comment: then rollback on the first error, why do you track all 8 operations separately

Comment: It might be better if you chain the calls, and only proceed if nothing goes wrong

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt !x & !y is not equal to !(x&y)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt `!x && !y` =  `!(x || y)`

Comment: I'm pretty sure, you do not need more than one variable. But I could be wrong.

Comment: yes I dont require more than one boolean. But If I got exception in one of my db call even continues the remaining calls.

Comment: I will post my Original code please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: @ShivaGoudA so you see, the issue is the design :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code have a bug initially.

```
if(flag = false && flag1 = false && ....){
  userTransaction = rollback;
}
```

`=` (assigning) is different than `==` (compare).

Next thing is with your current style you can reduce the code as

```
if(! flag || !flag1 ||  ....){
  userTransaction = rollback;
}
```

Because they are booleans you need not to check again with booleans.

Last thing I suggest is, where ever these variables are coming from , maintain a list and iterate over them to check all, with that way, you code related to checking remains constant even though `n` number of booleans you have.

Comment: "I want to rollback when one or more of 8 booleans have false." So `||`, rather than `&&`, surely?

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah. That is ||. Missed it. Thankyou.

Answer (score 4):

how about the following?

```
if(flag  && flag1  && ....){
     userTransaction = commit;
  } else {
      userTransaction = rollback;
  }
```

Comment: best option imho. simple and readable. could also be one line instruction.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the fastest way to handle this.

1. Write your flags into an List or an Array
2. test it like this

**As List:**

`if(!myList.contains(false)) //all true;`

**As Array**

`if(!myArray.asList().contains(false)) //all true;`

Comment: Instead of maintaining an array and converting it to list, I suggest to take a  List directly:)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ ty fixed it. As sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ said its easier and faster to handle it within a list

Comment: I think an array would be better. A list can only have boxed types. An array can have primitive types. `List<Boolean>` vs `bool[]`.

Comment: I Think it depends on the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform `and` operation on all values with [BooleanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#and(boolean...)) by Apache:

```
if (BooleanUtils.and(flag1, flag2, flag3, flag4)) {
    userTransaction = commit;
} else {
    userTransaction = rollback;
}
```

Or just do it usual way:

```
if (flag1 && flag2 && flag3 && flag4)) {
    userTransaction = commit;
} else {
    userTransaction = rollback;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need intermediate result, then you may try this:

```
boolean result = true;
boolean doRollback = true;
try {
  result = db.doSomething1() && result; // ? && true -> ?; 
  result = db.doSomething2() && result; // if result: false then ? && result -> false
  if (result) {userTransaction.commit(); doRollback = false;}
} finally {
  if (doRollback) userTransaction.rollback();
}
```

That would ensure that each db operations are executed ... and that result contains the final result.